# Converting a Java Array List into an XML string

Tags: java, xml, jsp, model-view-controller, jaxb

In my servlet (`getEmployee`), I create an instance of my dao(`EmployeeDAO`), then make an empty Array List (`arrayList`) and populate it with the method in my dao (`getTheEmployees`).

What I am trying to do is within the doGet of my servlet, take this Array List and convert the contents into an xml string. I will then grab this in my jsp page. I know I need to use JAXB to convert to an xml string but I cannot get this to work.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I am using this code:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
    Marshaller mars = jc.createMarshaller();    
    mars.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    mars.marshal(arrayList, sw);
    String xmlString = sw.toString();
```

All I get is the following error - at `java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`

Comment: Why can't you get JAXB to work exactly?

Comment: Code added to explain - @bdavies6086

Answer (score 0):

This is where you have a problem:

```
ArrayList arrayList = ...;
mars.marshal(arrayList, sw);
```

An ArrayList (or List or Collection) can never act as the root of a content tree to be marshalled: it would result in a sequence of XML elements (resulting from the list elements), and this isn't a valid XML document.

Most likely, you'll have to define a

```
class Root {
    List<X> arrayList = ...;
}
```

and create an object from this, with the list as its field, and marshal this.

If this doesn't meet your requirements you'll have to provide a sample of the XML you want, and the Java code for the list elements and descibe how these relate to each other.